# How do I format datetime in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to capture the date and time in this format:  "01/01/11 4:45 PM"

Can someone guide me on how to format in this dialog window or is there another method?

Many thanks.
Erik

[image]

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: like this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(new_ts, "%m/%d/%y %l:%i %p")
```